# Why getIdentifier is returning always 0 for a string

Tags: android, superclass

I'm trying to dynamically change the text and the title of an Activity Main1 which extended to Text1 where the titles and textes, I did this code but never worked:

```
public class MainText1 extends Text {


String  
tx1=text1,tx2=text2,tx3=text3,
tl1=title1, tl2=title2,tl3=title3,tl,tx;


    num = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("somekey1")); // this data is coming from the menu, it depends on which button is clicked

    tl="tl"+num;
    tx="tx"+num;

    stringId1 = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(tl, "string",  getPackageName());
    stringId2 = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(tx, "string", getPackageName());

    if (stringId1 > 0) {
         title=getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(stringId1);
         text2=getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(stringId2);
    }

    else
    {
         title=Integer.toString(stringId1);
         text2=Integer.toString(stringId2);
    }


    text1 = "<font color=#000080><b>" + title + "</b></font>";
    t1.setText(Html.fromHtml(text1));
    t2.setText(Html.fromHtml(text2));
```

the problem is that stringId1 and stringId2 giving 0 value.

Comment: Probably because the resource doesn't exist..

Comment: no it does exist and this is the super class code: `public class Text extends Activity {
 
 
 
 public String
 titl1="kar",
 tex1="ggggg",
 titl2="2222",
 tex2="kar2",
 
 titl3="333",
 tex3="kar3";}`

Comment: There might be some confusion here, you should read [the doc about resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html)

Comment: I agree with you i may have confused between string  variable and resources but do you have a quick clue please

Comment: use a map, key is `tlxx`, value is the value of `tlxx`

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what's a map and key, could you please give a simple example if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

As requested in the comments, with a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

```
Map<String, String> theMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
theMap.put("tx1", text1);
theMap.put("tx2", text2);
theMap.put("tx3", text3);
theMap.put("tl1", title1);
theMap.put("tl2", title2);
theMap.put("tl3", title3);

num = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("somekey1")); // this data is coming from the menu, it depends on which button is clicked

tl="tl"+num;
tx="tx"+num;

if (theMap.containsKey("tl") {
     title = theMap.get("tl");
} else {
     // do something
}

if (theMap.containsKey("tx") {
     text2 = theMap.get("tx");
} else {
     // do something
}
```

You might also want to put `theMap` in `Text` and expose some `getTitle(int)` and `getText(int)` method **or** use android [resources mecanism](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html)

---

Also if I may, I would advise reading [this java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)