# How to change a sting Variable name dynamically and programatically, this is challenging

Tags: android, string, variables, android-activity

I have MainText1 displays a text, when you click on button 3 in the Menu MainText1 displays text3 which is coming from the super class Text. What I want is that dynamically when you click on any button it reads the number and displayed the respective text, that's all about. ;) 
I want to get rid of switch case in my activity, so I'm trying now for 2days :( to change the name of the string variable dynamically, but I think I'm using a wrong code as string variable is different from resources (confused), here's my code, this really challenging me this weekend:

```
public class MainText1 extends Text {


String  
tx1=text1,tx2=text2,tx3=text3,
tx,stringReceived;//text1,text2...textn strings coming from the Super class Text


num = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("somekey1")); // this data is coming from the menu, it depends on which button is clicked

    tx="text"+num; // text is the name of the string variable, it should be in format like that : text1,text2,...textn which have predefined string content


    stringId = getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(tx, "string", getPackageName());

    if (stringId > 0) {

         stringReceived=getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(stringId);
```

Comment: Could you find another way of explaining what you're trying to achieve please?  You can't change the name of a variable programatically - that would make no sense.  What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Please see that link where it is more explained :[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28381146/why-getidentifier-is-returning-always-0-for-a-string)

Comment: I suspect you'll get more help if you explain the problem clearly and succinctly in one post. :-)

Comment: I think you should start by reading documentation and tutorials about Java and Android instead of writing code without knowing exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I have MainText1 displays a text, when you click on button 3 in the Menu  MainText1 displays text3 which is coming from the super class Text. What I want is that dynamically when you click on any button it reads the number and displayed the respective text, that's all about. ;)

Comment: The method specified in each button's "onClick" will be called with a View parameter.  If you have several buttons all calling the same onClick method, you can use this parameter to determine which one called it.  From your explanation and code, though, I'm far from certain this is what you are asking.

Comment: What is `Text`? How can you display `MainText1` as a text? Please post all of related classes (`Text` and `MainText1`), or otherwise, please describe your problem clearly. I'm afraid you're making the issue more complex than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're trying to do is to change a TextView contents. So, you could do the following:

```
public YourActivity extends Activity {

   //Here you will declare your layout items
   private Button button1;
   private Button button2;
   private Button button3;
   private TextView txtView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
        //Here you will get you layout elements
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1_id);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2_id);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3_id);
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtview_id);

        //Now you will have to set the onClickListeners
        button1.addOnCLickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            private onClick() {
                 //Set the text in the text view to the string related
                 //to button1
                 txtView.setText(getResources()
                                 .getString(R.string.button1_string);)
            }
        });
        button2.addOnCLickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            private onClick() {
                 //Set the text in the text view to the string related
                 //to button2
                 txtView.setText(getResources()
                                 .getString(R.string.button2_string);)
            }
        });
        button3.addOnCLickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            private onClick() {
                 //Set the text in the text view to the string related
                 //to button3
                 txtView.setText(getResources()
                                 .getString(R.string.button3_string);)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This should do the trick. Although, like the other guys suggested it, you should take a look at some tutorials before coding on